# Mudar o value do input com jquery pra um sistema de postagem

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse pequeno motor *AJAX*, estou usando *jQuery*, esse código é pra um sistema de postagem, mas não está funcionando.

A lógica é pra um cadastro de postagens com formulário usando 2 botões para envio *(submit)*. Um é para cadastrar somente e o outro é para cadastrar e publicar a postagem. Sendo que será salvo no campo *status* o *input* que será com *value* `0` e quando for publicar e cadastrar sera mudado o atributo *value* para `1`.

```
   //publicar e publicar e atualizar
    var button = $('.cadPub');
    var buttonCad = $('.cad');
    var cadastro = $('.formDados');//formulario
    cadastro.submit( function(){
        if(button){
            button.click(function(){
                $('.status').each(function(){
                    var input = $(this);
                    input .val(1);
                });
            });
        }else{
            $('.status').each(function(){
                var input = $(this);
                input .val(0);
            });
        }

    //CADASTRO
    if(button || buttonCad) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var cap = $(this).attr('data-controller');

        $.ajax({
            url: BASE + cap,
            data: {id: id},
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (data) {
                $.each(alerts, function (key, value) {
                    $('.alert').removeClass(value);
                });
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.retorno) {
                    $('.alerta').addClass(data.retorno[0]);
                    $('.icones').addClass(data.retorno[1]);//icone tem que passar no indice 1
                    $('.titulo').html(data.retorno[2]);//Titulo no indice 2
                    $('.result').html(data.retorno[3]);//Mensagem de retorno no indice 3
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: o codigo acima ficou fora da formatação do codigo fonte.Admin pode editar pra mim não sei usar muito esse editor.

Comment: Abre seu olho, couro que canta em Chico também canta em Francisco :D - pergunta editada!! E reeditada por Valdeir Psr

Comment: Acho que seria interessante postar a parte HTML envolvida na questão. Facilitaria o trabalho de quer quiser fazer testes.

Comment: o HTML o importaria seria o campo status ]que é simples  apenas um input com  name ="status" value="0" e o os 2 botoes submits cadastrar e o cadastrar e publicar. com as classes encapsulados cad e cadPub

Comment: Essa variável `alerts` em `$.each(alerts, function (key, value) {` vem de onde?

Comment: essa é a msg de sucess mas  esta certo oque queria é submeter o form de 2 jeitos um co cada botao e o cad  e o outro cad e publicar